# limit of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to calculate these two limits and I don't know where to start:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{e^{x-y}-1}{x^2-y^2}
$$
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+x^3y}
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this, it is often convenient to reduce them to one-variable limits.  For example:

In your first question, note that you can write
$$
\frac{e^{x-y}-1}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{1}{x+y}\cdot\frac{e^{x-y}-1}{x-y}.
$$
Now, as $(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)$, $x+y\rightarrow2$; what about the second fraction? Notice that this is precisely $f(x-y)$, where
$$
f(t):=\frac{e^t-1}{t}.
$$
As $(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)$, $x-y\rightarrow0$; can you figure out how $f(t)$ behaves as $t\rightarrow0$?

For the second one, you can do the same thing while making use of the hint given by njguliyev: note that
$$
\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+x^3y}=\frac{\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+x^3y}
$$
You can consider the first fraction as $g(x^2+y^2)$, where
$$
g(t):=\frac{\log(1+t)}{t},
$$
and figure out how to handle the second more directly.

Of course, it doesn't need to be true that any 2-variable limit can be done this way; but, if the functions $f$ and $g$ have limits at the desired points, then this will definitely work!

Answer (score 3):

Hints:
$$e^t = 1+t+o(t), \quad t \to 0$$
$$\ln(1+t)=t+o(t), \quad t \to 0.$$
Also note that $$\frac{x^2+y^2+x^3y}{x^2+y^2} \to 1, \quad x,y \to 0.$$

Comment: I doubt that the OP is allowed to use taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0):

IF the limit is known to exist, then you can calculate the limit by parametrizing both $x$ and $y$ as functions of a variable $t$ approaching  $t_0$ as long as this condition implies $x\to x_0$ implies $y\to y_0$ (a more difficult problem is to determine whether the limit exists). Do this in a convenient way by using *njguliyev* suggestion.